# Bug with newline after .insertHtml

Tags: ms-word, office-js

So I know that you previously mentioned a bug with the insertHtml method regarding a following newline.

Do you know when the bug is being fixed and alternatively when wordAPI 1.3 will be released?

I'm writing a word add-in and being able to insert a hyperlink without destroying formatting is extremely crucial for the app.

Does anyone have any solution for this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That bug was fixed since the July fork (builds 16.0.7341.XXXX) shipped around mid August. its also on the latest public update (Aug Fork)  16.0.7369+.  Can you please share the build where you are still observing this behavior?

The 1.3 API will ship soon, you can [try the preview](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/tree/WordJs_1.3_Openspec) who includes support for [hyperlinks](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/WordJs_1.3_Openspec/word/resources/range.md).